# Simple Grading system. Keep getting error 'undefined'. What I'm I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I keep getting the error 'undefined' but I only have one variable(grade) which I've already defined. Assistance will be highly appreciated.

```js
//Grading system:
// A = 84 and above       // D = 50 - 59
// B = 71 - 83            // E = 49 and below
// C =  60 - 70

function Grading_System(grade){
  var grade;

  switch(grade){
      case(grade >= 84):
        return "A";
        break;
      case(grade < 84 && grade > 70):
        return "B";
        break;
      case(grade >= 60 && grade <= 70):
        return "c";
        break;
      case(grade >= 50 && grade < 60):
        return "D";
        break;
      case(grade < 50):
        return "E";
        break;
  }
}
console.log(Grading_System(69));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check with `true`, because the expression is evaluated and checked against the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)'s value with a strict comparison.

```
switch (true) {
```

An you could omit the `break` statements, because the previous `return` statement ends the function.

```js
function getGrade(grade) {
    switch (true) {
        case (grade >= 84):
            return "A";
        case (grade < 84 && grade > 70):
            return "B";
        case (grade >= 60 && grade <= 70):
            return "c";
        case (grade >= 50 && grade < 60):
            return "D";
    }
    return "E";
}

console.log(getGrade(69));
```

Comment: wow thank you so much it's working. I'm trying to learn JS and it was really bugging me that I had to create an account lol

Answer (score 0):

You are re-declaring 'grade' inside of the function but not initialising it, so it will be undefined. Remove the line `var grade;` and see if it works. Also it is a good idea to include a `default`, so that if no switch matches, the default is given, and I don't think you need the 'break's if you are returning:

```
function Grading_System(grade){
  var grade;

  switch(grade){
      case(grade >= 84):
        return "A";
      case(grade < 84 && grade > 70):
        return "B";
      case(grade >= 60 && grade <= 70):
        return "c";
      case(grade >= 50 && grade < 60):
        return "D";
      case(grade < 50):
        return "E";
      default:
        return "F";
  }
}
```

Comment: actually the `var` is hoisted and nothing happens, because the function's parameter declaration declarese the variable already. the rsult is a superfluous additional delaration.

Comment: Nina's solution worked but thank you. seems I didn't have to declare the variable

Comment: I appreciate the help guys